# How to clear unread push notifications on the device from serverside?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Google Hangout:
You have unread notifications about your hangout chat on your lockscreen.
Open your hangout app on the PC and suddenly all the messages get removed from your lockscreen/unread notifications.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device is running iOS 7.0 there's a new type of remote notification that's "silent". Your app receive the notification and make some stuff without presenting something to the user. see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1